# Access to root variable within a @mixin

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to use the value of one root variable (which is defined by javascript) within a mixin as a condition of a @if. I think the example below is more clear than my explanation actually... Thanks for the help.

```
:root {
  --bu:A;
}

@mixin varCheck() {
    $var: var(--bu);
    @if ($var == A) {
        header {
            background-color: blue !important;
        }
    }
    @if ($var == B) {
        header {
            background-color: black !important;
        }
    }
}

@include varCheck();
```

Comment: The css var is created in the browser scope and the scss is compiled prior to that. So there's no way for sass to know what's in the `root` var